# What is correct way to load json file stored in the BytesIO object?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Data which I'm receiving is `bytes` therefore I need temporary *file-like* container. To my best knowledge `BytesIO` is *file-like* object, but `json.load()` doesn't work on it:

```
In [1]: import json
   ...: from io import BytesIO, TextIOWrapper

In [2]: d, b = dict(a=1, b=2), BytesIO()

In [3]: b.write(json.dumps(d).encode())
Out[3]: 16

In [4]: b.seek(0)
Out[4]: 0

In [5]: b.read()
Out[5]: b'{"a": 1, "b": 2}'

In [6]: b.seek(0)
Out[6]: 0

In [7]: json.load(b)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-233ac51d2711> in <module>()
----> 1 json.load(b)

/usr/lib/python3.5/json/__init__.py in load(fp, cls, object_hook, parse_float, parse_int, parse_constant, object_pairs_hook, **kw)
    266         cls=cls, object_hook=object_hook,
    267         parse_float=parse_float, parse_int=parse_int,
--> 268         parse_constant=parse_constant, object_pairs_hook=object_pairs_hook, **kw)
    269 
    270 

/usr/lib/python3.5/json/__init__.py in loads(s, encoding, cls, object_hook, parse_float, parse_int, parse_constant, object_pairs_hook, **kw)
    310     if not isinstance(s, str):
    311         raise TypeError('the JSON object must be str, not {!r}'.format(
--> 312                             s.__class__.__name__))
    313     if s.startswith(u'\ufeff'):
    314         raise JSONDecodeError("Unexpected UTF-8 BOM (decode using utf-8-sig)",

TypeError: the JSON object must be str, not 'bytes'
```

One method that works:

```
In [8]: json.loads(b.getvalue().decode())
Out[8]: {'a': 1, 'b': 2}
```

Another one, presumably more efficient?

```
In [10]: b.seek(0)
Out[10]: 0

In [11]: json.load(TextIOWrapper(b, encoding='utf-8'))
Out[11]: {'a': 1, 'b': 2}
```

Do I have more (better) alternatives? If no, which one of the above methods should be preferred?

Comment: Why don't you use a `StringIO`?

Comment: @Aran-Fey Data which I'm receiving is `bytes` and I need temporary file-like container. In the real life example I'm using `boto3.client('s3').download_fileobj()`.

Comment: You might be receiving the data as bytes, but you first need to decode that, as JSON is a Unicode string, not a bytestream.

Comment: @chepner I get it, but I cannot (prefer not) influence how `Fileobj` argument is handled inside the `download_fileobj()`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would recommend using [`TextIOWrapper`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.TextIOWrapper) for two reasons:

1. It gives you more control: Not only can you specify an encoding, but also how newlines should be handled (which would be relevant if you were parsing csv data, for example) and a number of other things.
2. It allows you to process the data in a streaming manner. Imagine you have a 10MB file that's not valid json - `fileobj.read().decode()` would needlessly load all 10MB into memory, but if you use `TextIOWrapper` then only a few bytes would be loaded before a `JsonDecodeError` is thrown.

Comment: Thanks, regarding `TextIOWrapper` I wasn't sure whether `JsonDecodeError` would be raised as soon as the first bits of incompatible `JSON` are detected. I assume `json.load()` would throw an exception only if the very first bits seem odd, but it would happily load entire 10M file if first bits seem as valid `JSON` but then in the middle become broken?

Comment: @NarūnasK It would only load as much data as necessary to detect that the file doesn't contain valid json.

Answer (score 12):

If you are using Python 3.5, upgrade to 3.6+

3.5

```
>>> import sys                                                                                                   

>>> sys.version                                                                                                  
'3.5.0 (default, Feb 16 2017, 15:47:16) \n[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 8.0.0 (clang-800.0.42.1)]'


>>> import json                                                                                                  

>>> from io import BytesIO                                                                                       

>>> d, b = dict(a=1, b=2), BytesIO()                                                                             

>>> b.write(json.dumps(d).encode())                                                                              
16


>>> b.seek(0)                                                                                                    
0


>>> json.load(b)                                                                                                 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/cmermingas/.pyenv/versions/3.5.0/lib/python3.5/json/__init__.py", line 268, in load
    parse_constant=parse_constant, object_pairs_hook=object_pairs_hook, **kw)
  File "/Users/cmermingas/.pyenv/versions/3.5.0/lib/python3.5/json/__init__.py", line 312, in loads
    s.__class__.__name__))
TypeError: the JSON object must be str, not 'bytes'

the JSON object must be str, not 'bytes'
```

3.6

```
>>> import sys

>>> sys.version
'3.6.0 (default, Jul 10 2017, 22:19:26) \n[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 8.1.0 (clang-802.0.42)]'

>>> import json

>>> from io import BytesIO

>>> d, b = dict(a=1, b=2), BytesIO()

>>> b.write(json.dumps(d).encode())
16

>>> b.seek(0)
0

>>> json.load(b)
{'a': 1, 'b': 2}
```

Comment: I'm looking for method, which would too work on other `python` versions, therefore upgrading is not an option.

Comment: `b.seek(0)` is crucial to avoid `JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1`

Answer (score -1):

Since you are dealing with JSON, which is purely texts, you should use `io.StringIO` instead of `io.BytesIO`:

```
>>> import json
>>> from io import StringIO
>>> d, b = dict(a=1, b=2), StringIO()
>>> b.write(json.dumps(d))
16
>>> b.seek(0)
0
>>> b.read()
'{"a": 1, "b": 2}'
>>> b.seek(0)
0
>>> json.load(b)
{'a': 1, 'b': 2}
```

Comment: Data which I'm receiving is `bytes` and I need temporary file-like container. In the real life example I'm using `boto3.client('s3').download_fileobj()`.

Comment: You should use the `bytes.decode` method to turn the `bytes` you receive into a string then.

Answer (score -1):

Tested with python 3.5

```py
import json
import socket, pycurl
from io import BytesIO

test_url='http://echo.jsontest.com/key/value/one/two' 

s = pycurl.Curl()
buffer= BytesIO()

s.setopt(s.URL, test_url)
s.setopt(s.HTTPHEADER, ['Host:' + 'localhost'])
s.setopt(s.WRITEDATA, buffer)
s.perform()

response = buffer.getvalue()
response = response.decode('utf-8')
# json.loads in python 3.5, not json.load
rj = json.loads(response)
srj = json.dumps(rj, indent=4, sort_keys=True)
print(srj)
```